# Replace string in the first column

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which looks like:

```
>TCONS_00000066_1     [3    -   170]
>TCONS_00000066_2     [174  -   206]
>TCONS_00000066_3     [2    -   223]
>TCONS_00000066_4     [210  -   281]
>TCONS_00000066_5     [227  -   316]
>TCONS_00000066_6     [1    -   324]
>TCONS_00000066_7     [285  -   338]
>TCONS_00000066_8     [335  -   373]
>TCONS_00000066_9     [342  -   377]
>TCONS_00000066_10    [328  -   465]
>TCONS_00000066_11    [377  -   487]
>TCONS_00000066_12    [469  -   546]
>TCONS_00000066_13    [390  -   551]
>TCONS_00000066_14    [518  -   556]
>TCONS_00000066_15    [537  -   490]
>TCONS_00006042_1     [9    -   62]
>TCONS_00006042_2     [87   -   146]
>TCONS_00006042_3     [150  -   203]
>TCONS_00006042_4     [2    -   220]
>TCONS_00006042_5     [1    -   255]
```

The file is tab delimited. I want to remove just the `_1` and `_2`....after every `>TCONS_0000****`. The rest of all the columns will be there as is.

Like:

```
>TCONS_00000066    [3    -   170]
>TCONS_00000066    [174  -   206]
>TCONS_00000066    [2    -   223]
>TCONS_00000066    [210  -   281]
>TCONS_00000066    [227  -   316]
>TCONS_00000066    [1    -   324]
>TCONS_00000066    [285  -   338]
>TCONS_00000066    [335  -   373]
```

Note: every `>TCONS_*`contains 8digits, like `>TCONS_00000066"..."`, `>TCONS_00987652"`

Comment: You seem to have many accounts. Please [merge them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and use only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/\([0-9]\)_[0-9]\+\t/\1\t/'
```

Search for a digit (named as \1) followed by an underscore followed by one or more digits followed by a tab and replace with named \1 and a tab

Answer (score 2):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F'[_ ]' '{$3=""}1' file > newfile
```